# Bourbon Refills: Tabs in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, bourbon, neat

Any one know how to get the tabs from Bourbon Refills to work in IE8?

I keep getting the tabs stacked on top of each other vs side by side.

I've added Selectivizr thinking it would correct the situation, but only fixes the grid from Neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Just removed the media queries inside the SASS for the tab layout and all is well.